# Appcelerator Titanium iOS Background Service Stop 30 Seconds

Tags: ios, service, background, titanium, appcelerator

Appcelerator Titanium iOS Background Service Stop 30 Seconds.
How do I do it without limits?

Comment: You don't. Background execution time is limited on ios

Comment: read more about it in the documentation: https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Background_Services-section-src-37539664_iOSBackgroundServices-Monitoringthebackgroundfetchnotification